# Is it possible to remove characters from a compressed file without extracting it?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, gzip, tarfile

I have a compressed file that's about 200 MB, in the form of a tar.gz file. I understand that I can extract the xml files in it. It contains several small and one 5 GB xml file. I'm trying to remove certain characters from the xml files.

So my very basic question is: is it even possible to accomplish this without ever extracting the content of the compressed file?

I'm trying to speed up the process of reading through xml files looking for characters to remove.

Comment: You want to *change* the contents of a comrpessed file but you do not want to *decompress* (and then recompress) it? That's not how `gzip` compression works.

Comment: When you say "extracting", do you actually mean "write to disk"? if so, it should be possible to achieve what you want without writing anything to the filesystem, but you will  have to uncompress the data, remove the unwanted characters, then recompress it.

Comment: If it's not writing to disk, where does it decompress? In memory? If so, that might become an issue when handling large files? I'm trying to understand gzip a little better.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to decompress, change, and then recompress the files.  There's no way around that.

However, this does not necessarily include *writing* the file to a storage.  You might be able to do the changes you like in a *streaming* fashion, i.e. that everything is only done in memory without ever having the complete decompressed file somewhere.  Unix uses pipes for such tasks.

Here is an example on how to do it:

1. Create two random files:

```
echo "hello world" > a
echo "hello world" > b
```

2. Create a compressed archive containing both:

```
tar -c -z -f x.tgz a b
```

3. Pipe the contents of the uncompressed archive through a changer.  Unfortunately I haven't found any shell-based way to do this but you also specified Python in the tags, and with the `tarfile` module you can achieve this:

Here is the file `tar.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import tarfile

tar_in  = tarfile.open(fileobj=sys.stdin.buffer,  mode='r:gz')
tar_out = tarfile.open(fileobj=sys.stdout.buffer, mode='w:gz')

for tar_info in tar_in:
  reader = tar_in.extractfile(tar_info)
  if tar_info.path == 'a':  # my example file names are "a" and "b"
    # now comes the code which makes our change:
    # we just skip the first two bytes in each file:
    reader.read(2)  # skip two bytes
    tar_info.size -= 2  # reduce size in info object as well
  # add the (maybe changed) file to the output:
  tar_out.addfile(tar_info, reader)

tar_out.close()
tar_in.close()
```

This can be called like this:

```
./tar.py < x.tgz > y.tgz
```

`y.tgz` will contain both files again, but in `a` the first two bytes will be skipped (so its contents will be `llo world`).

You will have noticed that you need to know the resulting size of your change beforehand.  `tar` is designed to handle *files*, and so it needs to write the size of the entry files into the tar info datagram which precedes every entry file in the resulting file, so I see no way around this.  With a compressed output it also isn't possible to skip back after writing all output and adjust the file size.

But as you phrased your question, this might be possible in your case.

All you will have to do is provide a file-like object (could be a `Popen` object's output stream) like `reader` in my simple example case.